# Data Structure with fast access to nth of elements satisfying condition

Tags: algorithm, vector, data-structures

I'm filling a stack/vector (a dynamically sized container with fast random access by index with insertion only at the end) with composite data (a struct, class, tuple…). For a specific attribute with a small set of possible values, I will want to access the nth of all elements in the stack where this attribute satisfies a condition. To achieve this, additional information can be stored along each composite or in a separate data structure.

Note that the vector is large and that the compared attribute has a small value range but is compared to a set of allowed values. Also the attributes aren't distributed evenly throughout composites in the vector.

Pseudocode of a O(n) naïve approach. How can I improve this:

```
enum Fruit { apple, orange, banana, potato };
struct c {
 Fruit a;
 Data d;
}

// Let's assume v has a length of many thousand and that the distribution of fruits is *not* completely random e.g. that maybe potato only rarely occurs or that bananas tend to come in packs
c getFruit(vector<c> v, set<Fruit> s, int n) {
 int counter=0;
 // iterate over all of v's indices
 for(int i=0 ; i<v.length; i+=1) {
  if(v[i].a in s) {
   if(n==counter) {
    return v[i];
   }
   counter+=1;
  }
 }
}

// note: The attribute is compared to a set (arbitrary combination of fruits)!
getFruit(largeVector, set{apple, orange, potato}, 15234)
```

Another approach would be to create a vector for each possible set of fruits which would be super fast O(1) but not so memory efficient.

(Although I do have to implement this now, I'm really just asking out of curiousity because my data is small enough to just go with the naïve approach.)

Any argument why there doesn't seem to a more efficient way is very much approved as well.

Edit: It should be noted that new elements may be appended between queries for indices using the algorithm in question so any caches have to grow with the vector and both growing the vector and this filtered access should be fast.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For each index of the vector, store the preceding number of each fruit.

Then you can do a binary search to find the first index where the sum of the desired fruit counts is sufficient.

If you don't want to use that much memory, then store the counts in a separate arrays, and only store them for every 16th index or so in the main array.  Your binary search will then get you an index within 16 positions of the desired answer, and you can do a linear scan from there.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll have to think for a second but I guess this really is the perfect solution I was looking for.

Comment: One small followup out of curiosity: Does this method have a certain name or is there a chance I might find this implemented in any library or database system?

Comment: Not that I know of.  I started thinking about an order statistic tree, and then optimized for your append-only use case: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic_tree